# How to delete all rows from all tables in Azure SQL Database?

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I tried to use the answer given [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899846/how-to-delete-all-rows-from-all-tables-in-a-sql-server-database). But Azure SQL does not have 'sp_MSForEachTable'.
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

`sp_MSForEachTable` is a not documented stored procedure.

We can manually create it in Azure SQL database.

Bellow is the whole statement of the full `sp_MSForEachTable`:

**Step 1:** create `[dbo].[sp_MSforeach_worker]`:

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[sp_MSforeach_worker]
        @command1 nvarchar(2000), @replacechar nchar(1) = N'?', @command2 nvarchar(2000) = null, @command3 nvarchar(2000) = null, @worker_type int =1
    as
    
    create table #qtemp (   /* Temp command storage */
        qnum                int             NOT NULL,
        qchar               nvarchar(2000)  COLLATE database_default NULL
    )

    set nocount on
    declare @name nvarchar(517), @namelen int, @q1 nvarchar(2000), @q2 nvarchar(2000)
   declare @q3 nvarchar(2000), @q4 nvarchar(2000), @q5 nvarchar(2000)
    declare @q6 nvarchar(2000), @q7 nvarchar(2000), @q8 nvarchar(2000), @q9 nvarchar(2000), @q10 nvarchar(2000)
    declare @cmd nvarchar(2000), @replacecharindex int, @useq tinyint, @usecmd tinyint, @nextcmd nvarchar(2000)
   declare @namesave nvarchar(517), @nametmp nvarchar(517), @nametmp2 nvarchar(258)

    declare @local_cursor cursor
    if @worker_type=1   
        set @local_cursor = hCForEachDatabase
    else
        set @local_cursor = hCForEachTable
    
    open @local_cursor
    fetch @local_cursor into @name

    while (@@fetch_status >= 0) begin

      select @namesave = @name
        select @useq = 1, @usecmd = 1, @cmd = @command1, @namelen = datalength(@name)
        while (@cmd is not null) begin      /* Generate @q* for exec() */
            select @replacecharindex = charindex(@replacechar, @cmd)
            while (@replacecharindex <> 0) begin

            /* 7.0, if name contains ' character, and the name has been single quoted in command, double all of them in dbname */
            /* if the name has not been single quoted in command, do not doulbe them */
            /* if name contains ] character, and the name has been [] quoted in command, double all of ] in dbname */
            select @name = @namesave
            select @namelen = datalength(@name)
            declare @tempindex int
            if (substring(@cmd, @replacecharindex - 1, 1) = N'''') begin
               /* if ? is inside of '', we need to double all the ' in name */
               select @name = REPLACE(@name, N'''', N'''''')
            end else if (substring(@cmd, @replacecharindex - 1, 1) = N'[') begin
               /* if ? is inside of [], we need to double all the ] in name */
               select @name = REPLACE(@name, N']', N']]')
            end else if ((@name LIKE N'%].%]') and (substring(@name, 1, 1) = N'[')) begin
               /* ? is NOT inside of [] nor '', and the name is in [owner].[name] format, handle it */
               /* !!! work around, when using LIKE to find string pattern, can't use '[', since LIKE operator is treating '[' as a wide char */
               select @tempindex = charindex(N'].[', @name)
               select @nametmp  = substring(@name, 2, @tempindex-2 )
               select @nametmp2 = substring(@name, @tempindex+3, len(@name)-@tempindex-3 )
               select @nametmp  = REPLACE(@nametmp, N']', N']]')
               select @nametmp2 = REPLACE(@nametmp2, N']', N']]')
               select @name = N'[' + @nametmp + N'].[' + @nametmp2 + ']'
            end else if ((@name LIKE N'%]') and (substring(@name, 1, 1) = N'[')) begin
               /* ? is NOT inside of [] nor '', and the name is in [name] format, handle it */
               /* j.i.c., since we should not fall into this case */
               /* !!! work around, when using LIKE to find string pattern, can't use '[', since LIKE operator is treating '[' as a wide char */
               select @nametmp = substring(@name, 2, len(@name)-2 )
               select @nametmp = REPLACE(@nametmp, N']', N']]')
               select @name = N'[' + @nametmp + N']'
            end
            /* Get the new length */
            select @namelen = datalength(@name)

            /* start normal process */
                if (datalength(@cmd) + @namelen - 1 > 2000) begin
                    /* Overflow; put preceding stuff into the temp table */
                    if (@useq > 9) begin
                        close @local_cursor
                        if @worker_type=1   
                            deallocate hCForEachDatabase
                        else
                            deallocate hCForEachTable
                        return 1
                    end
                    if (@replacecharindex < @namelen) begin
                        /* If this happened close to beginning, make sure expansion has enough room. */
                        /* In this case no trailing space can occur as the row ends with @name. */
                        select @nextcmd = substring(@cmd, 1, @replacecharindex)
                        select @cmd = substring(@cmd, @replacecharindex + 1, 2000)
                        select @nextcmd = stuff(@nextcmd, @replacecharindex, 1, @name)
                        select @replacecharindex = charindex(@replacechar, @cmd)
                        insert #qtemp values (@useq, @nextcmd)
                        select @useq = @useq + 1
                        continue
                    end
                    /* Move the string down and stuff() in-place. */
                    /* Because varchar columns trim trailing spaces, we may need to prepend one to the following string. */
                    /* In this case, the char to be replaced is moved over by one. */
                    insert #qtemp values (@useq, substring(@cmd, 1, @replacecharindex - 1))
                    if (substring(@cmd, @replacecharindex - 1, 1) = N' ') begin
                        select @cmd = N' ' + substring(@cmd, @replacecharindex, 2000)
                        select @replacecharindex = 2
                    end else begin
                        select @cmd = substring(@cmd, @replacecharindex, 2000)
                        select @replacecharindex = 1
                    end
                    select @useq = @useq + 1
                end
                select @cmd = stuff(@cmd, @replacecharindex, 1, @name)
                select @replacecharindex = charindex(@replacechar, @cmd)
            end

            /* Done replacing for current @cmd.  Get the next one and see if it's to be appended. */
            select @usecmd = @usecmd + 1
            select @nextcmd = case (@usecmd) when 2 then @command2 when 3 then @command3 else null end
            if (@nextcmd is not null and substring(@nextcmd, 1, 2) = N'++') begin
                insert #qtemp values (@useq, @cmd)
                select @cmd = substring(@nextcmd, 3, 2000), @useq = @useq + 1
                continue
            end

            /* Now exec() the generated @q*, and see if we had more commands to exec().  Continue even if errors. */
            /* Null them first as the no-result-set case won't. */
            select @q1 = null, @q2 = null, @q3 = null, @q4 = null, @q5 = null, @q6 = null, @q7 = null, @q8 = null, @q9 = null, @q10 = null
            select @q1 = qchar from #qtemp where qnum = 1
            select @q2 = qchar from #qtemp where qnum = 2
            select @q3 = qchar from #qtemp where qnum = 3
            select @q4 = qchar from #qtemp where qnum = 4
            select @q5 = qchar from #qtemp where qnum = 5
            select @q6 = qchar from #qtemp where qnum = 6
            select @q7 = qchar from #qtemp where qnum = 7
            select @q8 = qchar from #qtemp where qnum = 8
            select @q9 = qchar from #qtemp where qnum = 9
            select @q10 = qchar from #qtemp where qnum = 10
            truncate table #qtemp
            exec (@q1 + @q2 + @q3 + @q4 + @q5 + @q6 + @q7 + @q8 + @q9 + @q10 + @cmd)
            select @cmd = @nextcmd, @useq = 1
        end
    fetch @local_cursor into @name
    end /* while FETCH_SUCCESS */
    close @local_cursor
    if @worker_type=1   
        deallocate hCForEachDatabase
    else
        deallocate hCForEachTable
        
    return 0
  GO
```

**Step 2:** Create proc `[dbo].[sp_MSforeachtable]`

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[sp_MSforeachtable]
    @command1 nvarchar(2000), @replacechar nchar(1) = N'?', @command2 nvarchar(2000) = null,
  @command3 nvarchar(2000) = null, @whereand nvarchar(2000) = null,
    @precommand nvarchar(2000) = null, @postcommand nvarchar(2000) = null
AS
    declare @mscat nvarchar(12)
    select @mscat = ltrim(str(convert(int, 0x0002)))
    if (@precommand is not null)
        exec(@precommand)
   exec(N'declare hCForEachTable cursor global for select ''['' + REPLACE(schema_name(syso.schema_id), N'']'', N'']]'') + '']'' + ''.'' + ''['' + REPLACE(object_name(o.id), N'']'', N'']]'') + '']'' from dbo.sysobjects o join sys.all_objects syso on o.id = syso.object_id '
         + N' where OBJECTPROPERTY(o.id, N''IsUserTable'') = 1 ' + N' and o.category & ' + @mscat + N' = 0 '
         + @whereand)
    declare @retval int
    select @retval = @@error
    if (@retval = 0)
        exec @retval = dbo.sp_MSforeach_worker @command1, @replacechar, @command2, @command3, 0
    if (@retval = 0 and @postcommand is not null)
        exec(@postcommand)
    return @retval
GO
```

Then you won't get the message:  "The module 'sp_MSforeachtable' depends on the missing object 'dbo.sp_MSforeach_worker'. The module will still be created; however, it cannot run successfully until the object exists".

Ref: [A Copy Of sp_MSforeachtable Stored Procedure For Azure, Uses sp_MSforeach_worker](https://gist.github.com/metaskills/893599)

I tested and it works in Azure SQL database:

Delete all the table data:

```
--Delete all the table data.
EXEC sp_msforeachtable 'DELETE FROM ?'
```

[image]

Data check:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am getting below error when I try to execute above sp: "The module 'sp_MSforeachtable' depends on the missing object 'dbo.sp_MSforeach_worker'. The module will still be created; however, it cannot run successfully until the object exists"

Comment: Don't worry，the dbo.sp_MSfoech_worker proc is created afrer the first stored proc. It's exist.  The script includes the two stored proc.

Comment: Hi @deathrace, I edit my answer to make it clear. If my answer is helpful for you, please mark it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: hello @deathrace, does it work for you now? If you have any concerns, please let me know, thank you!